# Зачем в DFS на графах черный цвет?

Tags: графы

Кроме наглядности. Можно ли обойтись двумя метками: вершина посещена или нет?

Comment: @Al g, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В чистом DFS можно использовать только массив *Used*. Например:

```
void dfs(int v)
{
    Used[v] = true;
    for (...) //для всех доступных из v вершин
        if (!Used[текущая доступная из v])
            dfs(текущая доступная из v);
}
```

Comment: А третий цвет зачем тогда? Для модифицированных методов?